# Laravel Conditional Select with ->get

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get columns with some if conditions like "if column is null, show other column, if that is null too show the last column".

But didnt know how to make.

My code is like that

```
return $get->get([ "my.column", "my.column2", "my.column3"]);
```

Need to make it like

```
if(my.column){ my.column }elseif($my.column2){ my.column2 }else{ my.column3 }
```

Comment: Maybe not "if column is null", but "if column value for certain row is null"?

Comment: Do you want to fetch a specific column only from database or all the column? If u want all the columns just pass $get->get(); it will return all the columns and it's value

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT IF (my.column IS NULL, my.column, IF (my.column2 IS NULL, my.column2, my.column3)) AS new.column FROM table name ....";

DB::select($sql);

Comment: Yes. I have run it